# how to fire selection event for choose control in knockout js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Here i am providing my code, where i have put selection changed event for choose control in knockout js. 
i am new to this topic please help to how to fire event/ method when selection changed from drop down list/chosen list.

HTML Code:

```
<select id="manufacturer" onchange="console.log('changed')" class="gray" data-bind="foreach: manufacturerList, optionsCaption: 'Manufacturer'">
   <option data-bind="attr: { value: $data.mid }, html: $data.mname"></option>
</select>
```

Js code:

```
function memoryFilterData(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.mid = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.mname = ko.observable(data.name);
}

var Mfilterurl = "https://api.pcpartpicker.com/api/2015.1/part/category/filters/?apikey=5612661951b24c58979b7bb372c2a1f0809e2dc9&part_type=motherboard";
var MotherboardPcFilters = $.ajax({
    url: "services/PcPartpickerService.asmx/PcPartpickerList",
    type: "POST",
    data: "{ 'partlisturl' : '" + Mfilterurl + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
function categoryViewModel(tasks) {

    var self = this;

    self.manufacturerList = ko.observableArray([]);

    MotherboardPcFilters.done(function (allData) {
        var filterDoc = $.parseJSON(allData.d);
        for (var i = 0, len = filterDoc.filters.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var refInfo = filterDoc.filters[i];
            if (refInfo.parameter == "m") {
                manufacturers = refInfo.values;
            }
        }
        var manufacturer = $.map(manufacturers, function (item) { return new memoryFilterData(item) });
        self.manufacturerList(manufacturer);        
    })  
}

ko.applyBindings(new categoryViewModel(listOfTasks), document.getElementById("memoryFinder"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach already fires event.  Please, make your question more clear.

```html
<select onchange="console.log('changed')">
  <option >First</option>
  <option >Second</option>
  <option >Third</option>
</select>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waGuH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the data-bind on the select, you need a 'value' property for the selected value to be assigned - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

```
<select id="manufacturer"  
data-bind="foreach: manufacturerList, 
optionsCaption: 'Manufacturer', 
value:motherboardSelected">
    <option data-bind="attr: { value: $data.mid }, html: $data.mname"></option>
</select>
```

You can subscribe to that event by doing something like -

```
self.motherboardSelected.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The mobo selected is " + newValue);
});
```

I threw this into a codepen here - http://codepen.io/dmoojunk/pen/JXrmRz

Comment: In reality you likely don't want to use the subscribe feature here, but have other things bound up to the fact motherboardSelected is not undefined etc